# how to hide i element which is part of an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

When I click on a sort link, class `filter-link-active` and class `asc` is added to the anchor.

When these classes are added, the class `fa-sort` (font awesome) must be hide.

What happens: he hides all other classes `fa-sort` in the other anchors too! 
And it should **only hide** the `a-sort` in the current anchor itself

```js
$(document).on('click', '#' + val, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.filter-link.filter-link-active').not(this).removeClass('filter-link-active');
  $(this).toggleClass('filter-link-active');
  $('.filter-link').removeClass('asc desc');

  if (orderClass == 'desc' || orderClass == '') {
    $(this).addClass('asc');
    $('i').closest('.fa-sort').hide(); // hide font awesome icon in acnhor          
    orderClass = 'asc';
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('desc');
    orderClass = 'desc';
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a id="name" class="filter-link" href="#">Name<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="modified" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">Modified<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="size" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">Size<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="share" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">Share<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="view" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">View<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add whatever set orderClass and examples of rows to sort in a [mcve]

Comment: What's `val` in the first line? - please spend a LITTLE more time in giving us proper code to help you

Comment: `val` is an integer, 0, 1, 2 … The problem is this line: `$('i').closest('.fa-sort').hide();` It should hide the `i` with class`fa-sort`in the same anchor, and not in all the anchors

Comment: And this integer is set where?

Comment: the integers are set in a table and it reads the ibtegers to sort. But sorting is not problem. Only hide the font awesome icon when sort. So if class `asc` is added to anchor after click, hide the `i` with class `fa-sort` in the same anchor. That's the main issue!

Comment: Which is the element that you are clicking in your HTML?

Comment: [mcve] or I won't even look at the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below snippet. You can use `$(this).children('i').hide();` to select the `i` [child of](https://api.jquery.com/children/) `this`.

```js
var orderClass = '';

$("#name").click(function() {
  if (orderClass == 'desc' || orderClass == '') {
    $(this).addClass('asc');
    $(this).children('i').hide(); // hide font awesome icon in acnhor          
    orderClass = 'asc';
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('desc');
    orderClass = 'desc';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a id="name" class="filter-link" href="#">Name<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="modified" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">Modified<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="size" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">Size<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="share" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">Share<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="view" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">View<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Or you can use the `$("i", this)` selector to select the child `i` of `this`. This method accepts a second parameter called [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context).

```js
var orderClass = '';

$("#name").click(function() {
  if (orderClass == 'desc' || orderClass == '') {
    $(this).addClass('asc');
    $("i", this).hide(); // hide font awesome icon in acnhor          
    orderClass = 'asc';
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('desc');
    orderClass = 'desc';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a id="name" class="filter-link" href="#">Name<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="modified" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">Modified<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="size" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">Size<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="share" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">Share<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>
      <th><a id="view" class="filter-link filter-link-number" href="#">View<i class="fas fa-sort"></i></a></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(this).children('i').hide();` was exactly i was looking for! Now it works great. thnx

Comment: @mudrayakatusha Your welcome. I'm always glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help you :

`solution in JSF`

https://jsfiddle.net/erv0d5u6/82/